# Importing Subclasses from Modules in python

Tags: python, class, import, module

I'm Having an issue when Importing a series of modules and acessing classes within them.

This is my code:

```
import sys, os
for path, name, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()[:os.getcwd().rindex("Mario")+5]):
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(path))
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, Screen

WIDTH, HEIGHT = SIZE = 1200, 675
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, SRCALPHA)
current = None
screen_menu = Screen.Menu().add_widget(Widget.Button(WIDTH/2-25, HEIGHT/2-25, 50, 30))
```

When running I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Computing\Python\Mario\Global.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pygame, Screen
  File "I:\Computing\Python\Mario\screen\Screen.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pygame, Global
  File "I:\Computing\Python\Mario\Global.py", line 11, in <module>
    screen_menu = Screen.Menu().add_widget(Widget.Button(WIDTH/2-25, HEIGHT/2-25, 50, 30))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Menu'
[Finished in 2.9s with exit code 1]
```

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening, I have imported it and Menu is just a class within Screen, I can give you the Screen class if required!

Comment: @Blender Sadly I tried that and it said,`ImportError: No module named Menu`

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` at runtime is generally a mistake. It makes your code environment-dependent. Any changes to the import path should be made in the environment and there are many systems to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular dependency--`Screen` uses `Global` and `Global` uses `Screen`. Revise your code not to have any circular imports.

Comment: Will this fix the issue, or is that just good programming, also I used 'circular' imports to layout my code in a way which is easily readable as I originally started learning Java :)

Comment: Circular imports always reflect a suboptimal design, and can lead to bugs like the one you are seeing here. If you cannot see that this problem is caused by your circular imports (it is), that speaks all the more strongly in favor of the need to avoid them.

Comment: That did the trick, Thank you i'll bear that in mind in the future! :D